# NGC Controller detected but not recognized as a joystick

Tags: 18.04, drivers, adapter, gamepad

I'm currently trying to use a cheap Nintendo GameCube controller adapter for Wii U / Switch and PC (it has a toggle button to switch modes from console to computer) [(this one)](http://www.agptek.com/index.php/product/gamecube-controller-adapter-super-smash-bros-4-port-gamecube-ngc-controller-adapter-with-indicator-light-agptek-3-in-1-gc-controller-adapter-nintendo-switch-wii-u-pc-for-windows-vista-mac-os/) on my Ubuntu 18.04 computer.

I have found [this tool](https://github.com/ToadKing/wii-u-gc-adapter) to have it work (on console mode), but it doesn't work for me. The software acknowledges when I plug it in but nothing happens and the light indicator on the adapter stating that a controller is plugged in doesn't turn on.

On the other hand, when using PC mode, the light turns on and running `sudo evtest` shows my controller as an event (event 26 for that matter) ; here is what it says :

```
Input driver version is 1.0.1
Input device ID: bus 0x3 vendor 0x79 product 0x1846 version 0x110
Input device name: "Nintendo GameCube Controller Adapter"
Supported events:
  Event type 0 (EV_SYN)
  Event type 1 (EV_KEY)
    Event code 288 (BTN_TRIGGER)
    Event code 289 (BTN_THUMB)
    Event code 290 (BTN_THUMB2)
    Event code 291 (BTN_TOP)
    Event code 292 (BTN_TOP2)
    Event code 293 (BTN_PINKIE)
    Event code 294 (BTN_BASE)
    Event code 295 (BTN_BASE2)
    Event code 296 (BTN_BASE3)
    Event code 297 (BTN_BASE4)
    Event code 298 (BTN_BASE5)
    Event code 299 (BTN_BASE6)
    Event code 300 (?)
    Event code 301 (?)
    Event code 302 (?)
    Event code 303 (BTN_DEAD)
    Event code 304 (BTN_SOUTH)
    Event code 305 (BTN_EAST)
    Event code 306 (BTN_C)
    Event code 307 (BTN_NORTH)
    Event code 308 (BTN_WEST)
    Event code 309 (BTN_Z)
    Event code 310 (BTN_TL)
    Event code 311 (BTN_TR)
    Event code 312 (BTN_TL2)
    Event code 313 (BTN_TR2)
    Event code 314 (BTN_SELECT)
    Event code 315 (BTN_START)
    Event code 316 (BTN_MODE)
    Event code 317 (BTN_THUMBL)
    Event code 318 (BTN_THUMBR)
    Event code 319 (?)
    Event code 320 (BTN_TOOL_PEN)
    Event code 321 (BTN_TOOL_RUBBER)
    Event code 322 (BTN_TOOL_BRUSH)
    Event code 323 (BTN_TOOL_PENCIL)
    Event code 324 (BTN_TOOL_AIRBRUSH)
    Event code 325 (BTN_TOOL_FINGER)
    Event code 326 (BTN_TOOL_MOUSE)
    Event code 327 (BTN_TOOL_LENS)
    Event code 328 (BTN_TOOL_QUINTTAP)
    Event code 329 (?)
    Event code 330 (BTN_TOUCH)
    Event code 331 (BTN_STYLUS)
    Event code 332 (BTN_STYLUS2)
    Event code 333 (BTN_TOOL_DOUBLETAP)
    Event code 334 (BTN_TOOL_TRIPLETAP)
    Event code 335 (BTN_TOOL_QUADTAP)
    Event code 336 (BTN_GEAR_DOWN)
    Event code 337 (BTN_GEAR_UP)
    Event code 338 (?)
    Event code 339 (?)
    Event code 340 (?)
    Event code 341 (?)
    Event code 342 (?)
    Event code 343 (?)
    Event code 344 (?)
    Event code 345 (?)
    Event code 346 (?)
    Event code 347 (?)
    Event code 348 (?)
    Event code 349 (?)
    Event code 350 (?)
    Event code 351 (?)
  Event type 3 (EV_ABS)
    Event code 0 (ABS_X)
      Value    131
      Min        0
      Max      255
      Flat      15
    Event code 1 (ABS_Y)
      Value    124
      Min        0
      Max      255
      Flat      15
    Event code 2 (ABS_Z)
      Value    129
      Min        0
      Max      255
      Flat      15
    Event code 3 (ABS_RX)
      Value     32
      Min        0
      Max      255
      Flat      15
      Resolution      46
    Event code 4 (ABS_RY)
      Value     33
      Min        0
      Max      255
      Flat      15
      Resolution      46
    Event code 5 (ABS_RZ)
      Value    132
      Min        0
      Max      255
      Flat      15
      Resolution      46
    Event code 16 (ABS_HAT0X)
      Value      0
      Min       -1
      Max        1
    Event code 17 (ABS_HAT0Y)
      Value      0
      Min       -1
      Max        1
    Event code 18 (ABS_HAT1X)
      Value      0
      Min       -1
      Max        1
    Event code 19 (ABS_HAT1Y)
      Value      0
      Min       -1
      Max        1
    Event code 20 (ABS_HAT2X)
      Value      0
      Min       -1
      Max        1
    Event code 21 (ABS_HAT2Y)
      Value      0
      Min       -1
      Max        1
    Event code 22 (ABS_HAT3X)
      Value      0
      Min       -1
      Max        1
    Event code 23 (ABS_HAT3Y)
      Value      0
      Min       -1
      Max        1
  Event type 4 (EV_MSC)
    Event code 4 (MSC_SCAN)
Properties:
Testing ... (interrupt to exit)
Event: time 1592736137.754436, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 90002
Event: time 1592736137.754436, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 337 (BTN_GEAR_UP), value 1
Event: time 1592736137.754436, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1592736137.834549, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 90002
Event: time 1592736137.834549, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 337 (BTN_GEAR_UP), value 0
Event: time 1592736137.834549, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1592736139.499562, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 90008
Event: time 1592736139.499562, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 343 (?), value 1
```

As you can see at the end (I cut it but it was longer since I tried many buttons), every button and stick action is successfully detected, although I can't understand exactly what everything means. It seems to me that many actions are misinterpreted by the computer. The thing that bothers me most is probably the output of `sudo udevadm info` on event26, which says :

```
P: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.0/0003:0079:1846.000F/input/input37/event26
N: input/event26
S: input/by-id/usb-Nintendo_GameCube_Controller_Adapter_GH-GC-001_T10B-event-mouse
S: input/by-path/pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:3:1.0-event-mouse
E: DEVLINKS=/dev/input/by-id/usb-Nintendo_GameCube_Controller_Adapter_GH-GC-001_T10B-event-mouse /dev/input/by-path/pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:3:1.0-event-mouse
E: DEVNAME=/dev/input/event26
E: DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.0/0003:0079:1846.000F/input/input37/event26
E: ID_BUS=usb
E: ID_INPUT=1
E: ID_INPUT_TABLET=1
E: ID_MODEL=GameCube_Controller_Adapter
E: ID_MODEL_ENC=GameCube\x20Controller\x20Adapter
E: ID_MODEL_ID=1846
E: ID_PATH=pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:3:1.0
E: ID_PATH_TAG=pci-0000_00_14_0-usb-0_3_1_0
E: ID_REVISION=0100
E: ID_SERIAL=Nintendo_GameCube_Controller_Adapter_GH-GC-001_T10B
E: ID_SERIAL_SHORT=GH-GC-001_T10B
E: ID_TYPE=hid
E: ID_USB_DRIVER=usbhid
E: ID_USB_INTERFACES=:030000:
E: ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM=00
E: ID_VENDOR=Nintendo
E: ID_VENDOR_ENC=Nintendo
E: ID_VENDOR_ID=0079
E: LIBINPUT_DEVICE_GROUP=3/79/1846:usb-0000:00:14.0-3
E: MAJOR=13
E: MINOR=90
E: SUBSYSTEM=input
E: USEC_INITIALIZED=3899554972
```

This whole "event mouse" thing sounds to me like the computer thinks the controller is a mouse (although no joystick acts as a mouse).

Apart from uvtest, the controller hasn't any effect whatsoever on any application.
I have no jsX in /dev/input, only event[0-26], mice, mouse[0-4] ; I don't know if it is normal.

So I'm asking for your help ; it feels like we're close but I really don't know much about usb devices and device recognition so I'm a bit lost.

Thank you very much for your precious help!

EDIT. the joystick package is installed ; `sudo jstest /dev/input/event26` returns this :

```
Driver version is 0.8.0.
jstest is not fully compatible with your kernel. Unable to retrieve button map!
Joystick (Unknown) has 2 axes and 2 buttons.
Testing ... (interrupt to exit)

jstest: error reading: Invalid argument
```

Though I'm not sure it's relevant.

Also, taking inspiration from several threads and the rule file for Steam which I found in my computer, I created a rule in /lib/udev/rules.d which I put in a file called 89-gccontroller.rules :

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ENV{ID_CLASS}="joystick", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0079", ATTRS{idProduct}="1846", MODE="0666", ENV{ID_INPUT_JOYSTICK}="1", TAG+= "uaccess", ENV{ID_INPUT_MOUSE}=""
```

Apparently to no avail.